# How can I have an EOS Wallet?

Tags: wallet

I'm new to EOS but not to Bitcoin and Etherum.

I'm looking for a way to have an EOS Wallet but I don't know where I can do this.

I have bought some EOS on Binance exchange, at this time, deposit and withdrawal are not possible. But when it is be possible I want to do that *(withdrawal to a wallet)*

I see everywhere, ERC-20 Token through Etherum but before 1st June 2018 .. but this date is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the list of Wallets that support EOS:

- Scatter
- Exodus
- Jaxx
- MyEtherWallet

Personally, I use Exodus and Scatter

The community believes that there will be an official EOS Wallet when the main net launches, but you can currently use Exodus and Scatter for the main net as well.

Here you can see the work of the official EOS Wallet:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos-wallet-app

Answer (score 2):

Add [greymass](https://github.com/greymass/eos-voter) to this list of EOS wallets.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add to the list:

- Scatter Desktop https://github.com/GetScatter/ScatterDesktop
- SimplEOS https://github.com/eosrio/simpleos

I personally use SimplEOS and find it very easy to use.  Additionally, it assists in the process of helping you create an EOS account for others which is something that must be done by someone with an existing EOS account.  Not the easiest thing to do if you are just entering the EOS community.

Answer (score -1):

To create an eos wallet you have to stake a small portion of your eos. Then you can use one of the wallets that the other people suggested.

Comment: To create a wallet takes nothing because it is created locally.  A wallet is just an encrypted file that you use when you need to sign something, but it lives and signs locally.  That being said, to send a transfer command requires an account to transfer from and said account requires RAM to exist in (around 4kb).  The transfer command also requires CPU/NET.